# Is there a way to create a button in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have a visualization with a USA map, showing the airports of each state, and the connections of these airports. The search bar searches an airport, e.g LAX, and the visualization shows with blue color the searched airport and with red the rest, and the connections as well.

What I want now is to create a button to click, to hide/show the rules (connections) between each and every airport.

I have this code, formatted to work in the online editor (https://vega.github.io/editor)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "An interactive visualization of connections among major U.S. airports in 2008. Based on a U.S. airports example by Mike Bostock.",
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "search_input",
      "bind": {
        "input": "search",
        "placeholder": "Search Airport",
        "name": "Search:"
      },
      "value": ""
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "geoshape",
        "fill": "#ddd",
        "stroke": "#fff",
        "strokeWidth": 1
      },
      "data": {
        "url": "data/us-10m.json",
        "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "#000"},
      "data": {"url": "data/flights-airport.csv"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "lookup": "origin",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["latitude", "longitude"]
          }
        },
        {
          "filter": "datum.origin !== 'STX' && datum.origin !== 'SJU' && datum.origin !== 'BQN' && datum.origin !== 'STT' && datum.origin !== 'PSE'"
        },
        {
          "lookup": "destination",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["latitude", "longitude"]
          },
          "as": ["lat2", "lon2"]
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "latitude": {"field": "latitude"},
        "longitude": {"field": "longitude"},
        "latitude2": {"field": "lat2"},
        "longitude2": {"field": "lon2"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": [
            {"test": "button === ''", "value": 0},
            {
              "test": "search_input !== '' && !(datum.origin === search_input || datum.destination === search_input)",
              "value": 0
            }
          ],
          "value": 0.15
        }
      },
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "button",
          "bind": {"input": "button", "name": "On/Off Rules:"},
          "select": {"type": "point", "on": "click", "fields": ["origin"]},
          "value": "Click me"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle"},
      "data": {"url": "data/flights-airport.csv"},
      "transform": [
        {"aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "routes"}], "groupby": ["origin"]},
        {
          "lookup": "origin",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["state", "latitude", "longitude"]
          }
        },
        {"filter": "datum.state !== 'PR' && datum.state !== 'VI'"}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "latitude": {"field": "latitude"},
        "longitude": {"field": "longitude"},
        "size": {
          "field": "routes",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"rangeMax": 1000},
          "legend": null
        },
        "order": {"field": "routes", "sort": "descending"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "test(regexp(search_input,'i'),datum.origin)",
            "value": 0.95
          },
          "value": 0.25
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "test(regexp(search_input,'i'),datum.origin)",
            "value": "#6082B6"
          },
          "value": "#C70039"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "origin", "title": "Airport", "type": "nominal"},
          {"field": "state", "title": "State"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "projection": {"type": "albersUsa"},
  "width": 900,
  "height": 500,
  "config": {}
}
```

I have created a selection parameter `button`, which is the button that appears. I know that I must edit the opacity of the `rules` layer, but I cannot find the condition to make the opacity 0. Any help or direction to look into would be appreciated.